# Scribus: Don't want background color of text frame to print

Tags: pdf, textbox, pdf-generation, scribus

I am using Scribus 1.5.4

I want to create a PDF for a certificate format in which I can fill in the name of the person who got the certificate. I am using the text frame to fill in the name. I want the text frame to be visible to me but I dont want it to be printed on the certificate(i.e. print only the name).

I have set the borders of text frame to NONE and background color of the frame to white. But I want the text frame to be visible to me in the PDF BUT NOT print it. Does Scribus 1.5.4 provide any option like that?

Answer (score 0):

A strange question.

The simple answer is: When you work in Scribus you will see a thin border around each frame and that frame will not show up in the PDF.
if you  have disabled it in "View > Document > Show Frames", just re-enable it.

If you want more than that, you can also draw a rectangle in "behind" the text frame and mark the rectangle to be "non-printable". It's in the "XYZ" section of the "Window > Properties" palette.